# Приближенный интерфейс в Chrome на macOs и Linux ламает верстку

Tags: javascript, css, linux, google-chrome, macos

Проблема вот в чем:

Когда открываю страницу в Хроме, весь сайт становиться будто приближенным. Как видите - никакого приближения не использую, такая же проблема на macOs.

[image: Сайт на Хроме]

Вот та же страничка в Mozila

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как можно видеть - сдесь никакого приближения нету.
Надеюсь кто - то уже стыкался с похожей проблемой, надеюсь на вашу помощь, заранее спасибо.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `Как видите - никакого приближения не использую` где видим?

Comment: @StrangerintheQ, добавил скриншот.